# Delaying the offer letter

Tags: job-offer

I had interview on 23rd Feb and i was informed by HR through email on 24th saying that my profile was selected for that particular position.I asked her on phone about expected time to get offer letter . She replied that i would be receiving offer letter after 15 days.

Its already 21st March today and i am waiting for offer letter.
My question is that should i call her back or wait for some more time.

Comment: You are overdue on following up by one week. Follow up by email the minute the weekend is over. Follow up by email on the first day of the week every week thereafter. Keep up the job search, though - a promising job search will keep your mind busy.

Answer (score 8):

Never be afraid to check up on these things, they likely don't want to lose you if they sent it and you don't want to miss out by waiting. It's probably a postal issue more than anything else