# Offer letter delay

Tags: job-offer

I got selected for a company which is in Bangalore.

They promised me offer letter in 15 days. It's been 3 months and the hr still say that they are waiting for global team's approval. I asked them straight whether the offer is confirmed or should I stop calling and they say not to worry, the offer is confirmed but there is a delay.

Now I believe that it's a trap. I believe this company came to Hyderabad and selected candidates but didn't release offer letter to anyone.

I don't know why these big companies also play with the candidates time and emotions.

Is there any option to take action against them so that they don't cheat people like this?

Comment: This question has an answer here http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/43071/delaying-the-offer-letter
Notice the difference in wording. Your post sounds a little overdramatic (e.g. "it's a trap"). The reality is, a hiring manager might have made a conditional offer that won't materialize. If you've waited weeks and not received the offer in writing, you've got to keep looking for other opportunities.  It may be sloppy on their part but it doesn't mean they're "cheating" anyone.

Comment: Trap?  Why would they take the time and expense of and interview and purposefully not release and offer letter to anyone.  How would that benefit the company?

Answer (score 3):

I would take a moment to ask yourself why you would want to take action against the company - should other companies become aware that you're the type of candidate that sues companies that don't hire him, do you think they'd want to interview you?

To answer your question, my agency recruits globally and I am not aware of any country that has a legal precedent for a candidate to sue (or otherwise take action) after having an offer indefinitely extended. It's important to remember that the company isn't *doing* anything to you, really. They aren't trapping you, you are free to move along to another position if you'd like. What damages would you be suing for? Typically you need to prove that the sued party somehow caused you harm.

As for why they've extended your offer, it is unlikely that they are jerking your chain. Most recruiters don't like to be called by people they have no reason to talk to. If you were rejected for the position, the recruiter would tell you so you wouldn't bother him or her anymore. Since you apparently are active with checking in, you can be rest assured that the company/client is still interested in you, and the recruiter is interested in getting you the position. They may not be able to bring you on because the budget hasn't been approved, the project itself is going through restructuring, the company's client hasn't delivered payment or is ordering a project redefinition, HR policies could be changing forcing a hiring freeze, etc ad nauseum. Knowing that your recruiter has no reason to lie to you, do you want to jeopardize a possible employment opportunity by attacking the company?

Your best course of action is to inform your recruiter you will check in bi-weekly and politely add that you will begin searching for other opportunities. Then, search for other opportunities. Avoid burning bridges, you never know where they may lead.

Answer (score 0):

Chill out. It takes what it takes and even written offers are occasionally rescinded before the start date due to changes in the business environment such as an unexpected cancellation of a program. Some companies are very bureaucratic and take months and others can get the letters out instantly. And you have the extra complication of them recruiting in a foreign country, so they have more hoops to jump through. And sometimes people who have to do the approving are on vacation or emergency leave. Until you sign a contract though, you are under no obligation to them. At this point, you do not have an offer, you have a potential offer.

In the meantime, keep looking.  You may find something better before these people get their act together. You may be saved from a bad choice because they are clearly a slow company and that is not a company culture that you appear to be comfortable with. So be grateful that they have shown you that their company culture is not compatible with your needs before you get stuck with unhappily working in a foreign country.

As far as taking action against the company for cheating you? Well that is just not a good idea or even a reasonable idea. They haven't cheated you. Things happen. You are under no obligation to wait for them, so why would it be cheating? Further, being vindictive is a very bad way to start out your career and life. It harms you far more than it does them.